# Disable editing of column in DataGrid, but not for new row

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

It feels like there has to be an obvious answer here, but I can't find it.

I am using a DataGrid and want to disable one of the columns for editing for all rows that already exists. However, when I am adding a new row I don't want the column to be disabled for that row (the row at the end of the DataGrid).
IsReadOnly disable the whole column, including the last row.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Found a solution using styles, the property IsEnabled and a Converter. (Using that there is an ID column that not is set in the datagrid and therefore not > 0). If someone knows a good way of only setting properties for the row that is added in a better way, the answer will still be appreciated. (I am curious.)

Answer (score 0):

you have to make an action listener 
when a new row is created.
an action listener is triggered to to do an action . In the action you just 
tell him to make the  new row enables . if you want a portion of code I will give you :)